# How to make math questions with whole number solutions?

Tags: c#, random, calculator

I'm trying to make a simple program that makes division math tasks, and then checks if the user typed in the right answer to the calculation. Here are the basic code:

```
        //Get the 2 random numbers
        number1 = rand.Next(999) + 1;
        number2 = rand.Next(99) + 1;

        //Setup Calculation
        calculation = number1 + " / " + number2 + " =";
```

The problem is that a calculation like this: 699 / 58 = 12.05172413. It has too many digits. I need the program to only make calculations where the answer is a whole number.

My first idea is to make the random numbers be 10,20,30,40,50...
But I'm not sure if you can specify the random numbers like that?

Comment: Pick a random denominator and a random "answer", then calculate the proper numerator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about turning it around and multiplying:

```
   //Get the 2 random numbers
   //number1 = rand.Next(999) + 1;
    number2 = rand.Next(99) + 1;
    number1 = number2 * (rand.Next(9) + 1); // so it is a whole number multiple

    //Setup Calculation
    calculation = number1 + " / " + number2 + " =";
```

So you always have a whole number multiple.

Answer (score 3):

One possible solution is to instead of generating the two numbers to divide, you generate the denominator and the result, then get the numerator by multiplying these, guaranteeing that the result is always a whole number.

Answer (score 1):

To get random digits as multiples of 10,

```
     num=(rand.Next(10)+1)*10
```

Comment: Thanks Man, i've written that in my notes! says nothing about it in my book.